# Gas Estimation Fee on Tron Mainnet

Tags: blockchain, web3js, tron

I am encountering an issue with getting the estimation fee on Tron. Currently, I am using the `https://nile.trongrid.io/wallet/estimateenergy` endpoint on the Nile testnet,

but I need to transition to the mainnet for estimation. However, this endpoint does not work on the mainnet. Is there an alternative method to obtain the estimation gas fee on the Tron mainnet?